# How to display only month in JQuery Full calendar header/Title

Tags: jquery

How can I change the title/header of the jquery calendar. Code I used:

```
 header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
```

I only want to show Month instead of the "Day month, year" format in the header. 
**Note: I am using full calander:**

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});
```

Help please

Comment: which jQuery calendar are you on about? is it the jQuery-UI http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ?

Comment: I think it's [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

Comment: $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});

Comment: simply you can hide it with css on the page

Comment: No, I only want to show Month

Comment: I don't want to hide. Just want to display month instead of long date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody Knew the answer. It was setting the title attribute:
As:

```
titleFormat: {
                month: 'MMMM'                // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `center: 'title'` and add `titleFormat: 'MMM'`